# How to call an update on the main thread

Tags: ios, swift

I have a private `NSManagedObjectContext` queue that I'm using to save an entity to Core Data. After it has finished saving, I want to send out an NSNotification. However, it doesn't seem to like me sending out the notification from the private queue. This is my code for the private queue:

```
let parentManagedContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!
let privateManagedContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
privateManagedContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = parentManagedContext.persistentStoreCoordinator

privateManagedContext.performBlock {
    ...
    // Save the entity
    do {
        try privateManagedContext.save()
        // Send out NSNotification here
    }
}
```

How do I add a block within `performBlock` to run on the main thread?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so minutes after I posted this question I figured out the answer. All I had to do was add this code after the `try privateManagedContext.save()` code:

```
NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ 
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(kNotificationName, object: nil)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(kNotificationName, object: nil)
}
```